# Use IIS configure the reverse proxy, rewrite header Variables not work

Tags: iis

I'm using IIS(Windows2022) to configure the reverse proxy. I have installed the URL Rewrite and ARR modules, I configure them like this:

1, add "Allowed Server Variables": HTTP_Upgrade, HTTP_Connection, HTTP_Host.

2, add a config file like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_UPGRADE" value="{$HTTP_UPGRADE}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_CONNECTION" value="upgrade" />
                        <set name="HTTP_HOST" value="{$HTTP_HOST}" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But the request headers received by my backend server are still not modified. connection not change
[image]
it not change to upgrade.

i want to rewrite CONNECTION value to upgrade.

Comment: Please make sure you have enabled HTTP keep-alives, open iis -> In the Home pane, double-click HTTP Response Headers -> n the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane -> In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, check the box to enable HTTP keep-alives.

Comment: @samwu I think IIS URL write can't modify some serverVariables like CONNECTION...The only way is use nginx

Comment: i add "Allowed Server Variables": HTTP_Upgrade, HTTP_CONNECTION, HTTP_HOST, HTTP_COOKIE. but but...ONLY Cookie be modified to 123123.
Other still not modified...

Comment: Yes, I did not find HTTP_CONNECTION in [IIS server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables), so url rewrite cannot modify its value.